# Get custom claims from a JWT using Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin, jwt

I'm using Owin with JWTBearerAuthentication to authorize users and validate their tokens. I'm doing it like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        string issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("auth_issuer");
        string audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("auth_clientId");
        byte[] secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("auth_secret"));

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions 
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new [] { audience },
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, I have some custom claims in my token, and want to use their values in my ApiController, which looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("endpoint")]
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    [Route("action")]
    [Authorize]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(string someValue)
    {
        bool res = DoSomeAction.withTheString(someValue);

        if (res)
        {
            return Ok<string>(someValue);
        }

        return InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

Is there anything like `User.Claims["myCustomClaim"].Value`, which provides the values of all claims?

Thank you,
Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might help:

```
var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        return identity.Claims.Select(c => new
        {
            Type = c.Type,
            Value = c.Value
        });
```

Comment: This returns null, but debugging the identity object shows that `identity -> Non-Public members -> m_instanceClaims` contains the claims I want to access. How do I access this object?
EDIT: I guess my token or anything else was wrong, after rebooting and using another token, it works. Thank you!